# EF - DistinctBy on an IQueryable?

Tags: entity-framework, linq-to-entities

Say I have this where I want to get every person in group 42, but I want to get an `IQueryable<string>` of each unique first name in the database (PS - I know I can call `AsQueryable()` after the `Select` but that's not what I'm interested in doing - I want the database to perform the distinct, not the program):

```
MyEfContextContainer db = new MyEfContextContainer();
IQueryable<string> uniqueFirstNames = 
    db.People
    .Where(x=> x.GroupId == 42)
    .DistinctBy(c=> c.FirstName)
    .Select(c=> c.FirstName);
```

From what I can tell of how EF/LINQ to Entities handles the `DistinctBy` extension method, a store query is executed when `DistinctBy` is invoked and a list of ALL items in the database that match the `Where` is retrieved, then C# returns an `IEnumerable<T>` from the `DistinctBy` method that matches the expression sent to `DistinctBy`.

If there are millions of names in the list this is very inefficient.

I am interested in being able to do this efficiently, hopefully by having the store query only return a result set of all of the unique FirstNames in the table. I might, for example, want to return that `IQueryable<string>` as part of a repository where it is not okay for performance reasons to have millions of items grabbed and processed by `DistinctBy` to just return unique values. This would increase request processing time to an unacceptable level.

Is there any way to do this? Am I missing something? This is only a simple example, obviously in a real application objects more complex than string would be the subject of a query to the repository.

Answer (score 32):

I wrote this extension:

```cs
public static IQueryable<TSource> DistinctBy<TSource, TKey>  (this IQueryable<TSource> source, Expression<Func<TSource, TKey>> keySelector)
{
    return source.GroupBy(keySelector).Select(x => x.FirstOrDefault());
}
```

To make a distinct selection based on a property, e.g. Id, I just call:

```cs
res = res.DistinctBy(x => x.Id);
```

Comment: Wouldn't be better to use `First` instead of `FirstOrDefault` ? It would be great if MS implement this ticket: https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/27470

Answer (score 17):

With `IQueryable` you have to do it yourself:

```
db.People
  .Where(x => x.GroupId == 42)
  .GroupBy(c => c.FirstName)
  .Select(g => g.FirstOrDefault());
```

MoreLinq's `DistinctBy` method is an extension method on `IEnumerable<T>`, so it does accept an `IQueryable<T>`, but inside the method it acts as an `IEnumerable<T>`. It is the same effect as doing `db.People.AsEnumerable().DistinctBy()`