# Performance difference between GroupBy and MoreLinq's DistinctBy

Tags: c#, .net, linq, morelinq

Reading [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14321013/distinct-in-linq-based-on-only-one-field-of-the-table) question (and answer) I found out that there are at least two ways of get distinct items off an `IQueryabe` while still getting to choose what to filter by. Those two methods being:

```
table.GroupBy(x => x.field).Select(x => x.FirstOrDefault());
```

or using MoreLinqs `DistinctBy`

```
table.DistinctBy(x => x.field);
```

But that thread doesn't explain the performance difference and when I should use the one over the other. So when do I want to use one over the other?

Comment: [race your horses](https://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/) Note that MoreLinq's `DistinctBy` works **in memory**, it's not translated to sql and not executed by the db. `GroupyBy` might be implemented by your query provider and executed on the db.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a very big difference in what they do and thus the performance difference is expected. 
`GroupBy` will create a collection for each key in the original collection before passing it to the `Select`. `DistinctBy` needs to only keep a hashset with weather it has encountered the key before, so it can be much faster.

If `DistinctBy` is enough for you always use it, only use `GroupBy` if you need the elements in each group.

Also for LINQ to EF for example the `DistinctBy` operator will not work.

Comment: So if I have an `IQueryable ` of 1000 items out of which only two are duplicates `GroupBy` will create a collection 999 `collection<OriginalItem>`?

Comment: Yes is will create `IGrouping<out TKey, out TElement>`. But you should take care, `IQueryable<T>`, will probably not have the `DistincyBy` operator implemented for Entity Framework, so it will fail at runtime. This discussion applies for in memory LINQ. For EF the `DistinctBy` operator implementations I've seen actually use `GroupBy` under the hood and will not have any performance difference (for ex: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32619338/ef-distinctby-on-an-iqueryable)

Comment: DistinctBy is a 3rd party lib