# Take one and skip other duplicate item in a child table

Tags: linq, entity-framework-core, ef-core-2.1

I have a list of Items and every item have some list, Now I wants to select Distinct items of child. I have tried like below but it's not working.

```
var items = await _context.Items.
Include(i => i.Tags.Distinct()).
Include(i => i.Comments).
OrderBy(i => i.Title).ToListAsync();

//Tag items
TagId    -   tag
------------------
  1   ---   A 
  2   ---   B 
  3   ---   B 
  4   ---   C 
  5   ---   D 
  6   ---   D 
  7   ---   F
//Expected Result
Item.Tags -> [A,B,C,D,F]
```

how can I do this in EF Core? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [MoreLinq](https://github.com/morelinq/MoreLINQ) library to get `DistinctBy` or write your own using [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40573585/177416).

Then use this:

```
var items = await _context.Items.
    Include(i => i.Tags).
    Include(i => i.Comments).
    OrderBy(i => i.Title).
    DistinctBy(d => d.Tags.tag).
    ToListAsync();
```

You want to get distinct records based on one column; so that should do it.

Comment: `Tags` is a collection of `tag` so how it's possible to get it's property like `Tags.tag`?

Comment: You can also do this using standard Linq: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4158364/177416

Answer (score 1):

Apparently you have a table of `Items`, where every `Item` has zero or more `Tags`. Furthermore the `Items` have a property `Comments`, of which we do not know whether it is one string, or a collection of zero or more strings. Furthermore every `Item` has a `Title`.

Now you want all properties of Items, each with its `Comments`, and a list of unique `Tags` of the items. Ordered by `Title`

One of the slower parts of database queries is the transport of the selected data from the database management system to your local process. Hence it is wise to limit the amount of data to the minimum you are really using.

It seems that the `Tags` of the `Items` are in a separate table. Every `Item` has zero or more `Tags`, every `Tag` belongs to exactly one item. A simple one-to-many relation with a foreign key `Tag.ItemId`.

If `Item` with `Id` 300 has 1000 `Tags`, then you know that every one of these 1000 `Tags` has a foreign key `ItemId` of which you know that it has a value of 300. What a waste if you would transport all these foreign keys to your local process.

> Whenever you query data to inspect it, `Select` only the properties
>   you really plan to use. Only use `Include` if you plan to update the
>   included item.

So your query will be:

```
var query = myDbContext.Items
    .Where(item => ...)                // only if you do not want all items
    .OrderBy(item => item.Title)       // if you Sort here and do not need the Title
                                       // you don't have to Select it
    .Select(item => new
    {   // select only the properties you plan to use
        Id = item.Id,
        Title = item.Title,
        Comments = item.Comments,      // use this if there is only one item, otherwise
        Comments = item.Comments       // use this version if Item has zero or more Comments
           .Where(comment => ...)      // only if you do not want all comments
           .Select(comment => new
           {   // again, select only the Comments you plan to use
               Id = comment.Id,
               Text = comment.Text,

               // no need for the foreign key, you already know the value:
               // ItemId = comment.ItemId,
           })
           .ToList();

           Tags = item.Tags.Select(tag => new
           {   // Select only the properties you need
               Id = tag.Id,
               Type = tag.Type,
               Text = tag.Text,

               // No need for the foreign key, you already know the value
               // ItemId = tag.ItemId,
           })
           .Distinct()
           .ToList(),
     });

var fetchedData = await query.ToListAsync();
```

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tried it, but I'd say you put .Distinct() in the wrong place.

```
var items = await _context.Items
        .Include(i => i.Tags)
        .Include(i => i.Comments).
        .OrderBy(i => i.Title)
        .Select(i => { i.Tags = i.Tags.GroupBy(x => x.Tag).Select(x => x.First()); return i; })
        .ToListAsync();
```